# C Pointers Stucture, incompatiable types

Tags: c, debugging

How do I get the a pointer in a structure, to point to a same type of data that is inside another structure?

Linked list:

```
typedef struct Item {
    struct Item *ptr; //point to next one
} MyItem;

    typedef struct Collection {
     int x;        
     MyItem coll_ptr; //structure, not a pointer
    } MyCollection
```

In a function I have:

```
functionX(MyCollection* collection)
{
    MyItem *var= malloc(sizeof(MyItem));
    var->ptr = collection->coll_ptr;   //ERROR: incompatible types
}
```

Assuming coll_ptr is poitning to a valid `MyItem` structure, how can I get the new->ptr to point to that same structure?

However, if I do `var->ptr = &collection->coll_ptr;` I don't get the error,

but is this the address of that entire structure?

or that specific item in the collection structure?
(say collection has other items, not just the pointer)?

***Clarification to Question***

var->prt needs to point to the coll_ptr structure, that is inside collection.

is this the correct way to do that: `var->ptr = collection->coll_ptr;`

or is this: `var->ptr = &(collection->coll_ptr);`

**Answer from help below**
`collection->coll_ptr;` is not a pointer so the & is needed, in front of the statement to reference the address of that element.

Comment: @william-andrew-montgomery: but is it correct - or is it poitning at what is intended?

Comment: I am confused by the question. Variable `new` is created and then something called `var` is dereferenced; are these intended to be synonyms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, observe that `new` is a reserved word in C++ and it cannot be used as variable name.

Anyway, you want to set the value of `var->ptr` to `collection->coll_ptr->ptr`, because that's where your `MyItem` type is.

Comment: @havenard: is 'collection->coll_ptr->ptr' the pointer in that structure I am trying to get to? I want a pointer to that structure, not it's contents....or is that doing this?

Comment: As of right now @P.S., after you edited the code, your line should pretty much work. Except perhaps for the variable named `new`.

Answer (score 2):

When compiling a .c file there's no problem with the word `new` . And there is no single problem with your code when i compiled it using Code::Blocks default C/C++ compiler which is described as follows :

> This plugin is an interface to various compilers:
>
> GNU GCC compiler
>
> Microsoft Visual C++ Free Toolkit 2003
>
> Borland C++ Compiler 5.5

Your code has 0 error , check out your compiler .

```
    #include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct Item {
        struct Item *ptr;
    } MyItem;

    typedef struct Collection {
        MyItem *coll_ptr;
    } MyCollection;

    void functionX(MyCollection* collection)
    {
        MyItem *new = malloc(sizeof(MyItem));
        new->ptr = collection->coll_ptr;   //ERROR: incompatible types
    }

    int main(){
            MyCollection Ha ;
            functionX(&Ha);
            return 0;
    }
```

Compiler :

> Process terminated with status 0 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
>
> 0 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds)